# How to get path of opened file in c++

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to implement a file save function for my notepad project.

The file save function should be implemented like this :

1. Click Save Menu
2. If the texts were written on notepad never saved, print file dialog and set file path and then save.
3. If the texts already saved(may be modified), just save.

I think the path of the current text file is required for checking whether never or already saved.

(If the file never saved, the path doesn't exist.)

Then, How to get the path of the current file?

I am working with VS2019, MFC.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the file is never saved, the file does not exist. If you modify a file, you already opened a file (or saved a new file) and therefore should know about the path

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Yes. One of the solution is to save file path when open or save(first time) file. The file path would exists somewhere and be used for checking whether never or already saved. But I feel unnatural about this solution. For example, It isn't suitable to determine whether never or already saved by whether the title of file is "Untitled" or not. So I think it is more appropriate to find the file path at every moment if possible.

Comment: But why? You either can use a bool: FileExist or a string with Path which is either NULL for non-existing or set if fthe file is saved? You will need this property more than once later I would guess

Comment: You cannot get the path from the 'current file'. You have to devise some mechanism of your own to save any file name that has been used for the current file to this point.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? If YOU open a file, log it in a variable. SIMPLE. There is no complicated things to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you use the document view architecture, you have a **CDocument** method that tell you the path of your files or, NULL/empty if the file is not saved yet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdocument-class?view=vs-2019#getpathname

"The document's fully qualified path. This string is empty if the document has not been saved or does not have a disk file associated with it."